# Pattern not rendering when using group element (g) in d3, but rendering when made as an individual SVG

Tags: d3.js, svg, ecmascript-6

I have a use case where I have to load a hash pattern inside an svg.

So since, its a graph we are using inner elements as group elements like this.

```
<svg>
... ... ...
<g class="random-data-task" aria-selected="false" aria-describedby="task3">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern-stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)" width="2" height="23">
            <rect width="341.33333333333337" height="23" style="fill: #fff;" x="153.6217133163698" y="50"></rect>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="153.6217133163698" y="50" width="341.33333333333337" height="23" class="random-data-bar" style="fill: #f4f4f4;"></rect>
    <rect x="153.6217133163698" y="50" width="341.33333333333337" height="23" class="random-data-bar" style="fill: url(#pattern-stripe); stroke: #f4f4f4; opacity: 1;"></rect>
</g>
... ... ... </svg>
```

So, while doing this, the pattern is not visible.

But when I try to use an svg and make each rect (bar) as svg, I'm able to see the pattern I want, but this won't re-scale my bars when I zoom in or out, since its going to rendered in a time-range.

```
<svg>
... ... ...
<svg class="random-data-task" aria-selected="false" aria-describedby="task3">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern-stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)" width="2" height="23">
            <rect width="341.33333333333337" height="23" style="fill: #fff;" x="153.6217133163698" y="50"></rect>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="153.6217133163698" y="50" width="341.33333333333337" height="23" class="random-data-bar" style="fill: #f4f4f4;"></rect>
    <rect x="153.6217133163698" y="50" width="341.33333333333337" height="23" class="random-data-bar" style="fill: url(#pattern-stripe); stroke: #f4f4f4; opacity: 1;"></rect>
</svg>
... ... ...
```

here is the code for my hash bars looks like

```
const renderHashedBarGroup = (scale, taskData, taskPath) => {
const _args = generatorArgs(scale, taskData, taskPath);
(taskData.isBackGround ? getBackgroundHashedBar : getForeGroundHashedBar)(
    _args.path.append("defs"),
    _args.path,
    _args.x,
    _args.y,
    _args.width,
    _args.height,
    taskData.isBackGround ? "#d3d4d5" : "#f4f4f4"
);};

const getBackgroundHashedBar = (defs, path, x, y, width, height, color) => {
const patternId = "pattern-stripe-background";
if (d3.select(`#${patternId}`).empty()) {
    defs.append("pattern")
        .attr("id", patternId)
        .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("patternTransform", "rotate(135)")
        .attr("width", "7")
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", "2")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("style", "fill: #fff;");
}
// Draw the background rect
getRect(path, x, y, width, height)
    .classed(styles.taskBar, true)
    .attr("style", `fill: ${color}; stroke: ${color}; opacity: 0.3`);
// Opacity for bar with hashes
getRect(path, x, y, width, height)
    .classed(styles.taskBar, true)
    .attr("style", `fill: url(#${patternId}); opacity: 0.7;`);
return path; };

const drawTasks = (scale, config, trackLabel, taskGroupPath, tasks) => {
const taskPath = taskGroupPath
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(
        tasks.map((a) =>
            processTask(config, trackLabel, utils.deepClone(a))
        )
    );
taskPath
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed(styles.task, true)
    .attr("aria-selected", false)
    .attr("aria-describedby", (d) => d.key)
    .each(function(d) {
        d.percentage
            ? renderPercentageBarGroup(scale, d, this)
            : d.hasOwnProperty("isHashed") && d.isHashed
                ? renderHashedBarGroup(scale, d, this)
                : renderBarGroup(scale, d, this);
    });
taskPath
    .exit()
    .transition(constants.d3Transition)
    .remove();
```

};

Comment: So what is your question?  You seem to have described a problem, but haven't said what you want to achieve. :)  Also please include a [mcve] in your question, so we can see the problem in action ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't understand what is happening first remove all that complicates the stuff. Here it is the rotation and almost all colors used are nearly white.

Even setting the rotation to 0 and colors to bright contrasty values we do not see any pattern.

The reason is that the pattern repeats every 2 pixels `width="2"

```
<pattern id="pattern-stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
         patternTransform="rotate(0)" width="2" height="23">
```

But only at `x=153` something is defined in the pattern

```
<rect width="341" height="23" style="fill: #fff;" x="153" y="50"></rect>
```

Result you don't see a thing.

If you set the `width` to a larger value then the x coord of your pattern rect you see in both cases a pattern.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<svg width="700" height="100">
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern-stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)" width="200" height="23">
<rect width="341" height="23" fill="yellow" x="153" y="0"></rect>
</pattern>
</defs>
<g class="random-data-task" aria-selected="false" aria-describedby="task3">
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" style="fill: #f40000;"></rect>
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" fill="url(#pattern-stripe)" style="stroke: #00f400; opacity: 1;"></rect>
</g>
</svg>

<hr/>

<svg width="700" height="100">
<svg>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern-stripe2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)" width="200" height="23">
    <rect width="41" height="23" fill="lime" x="153" y="0"></rect>
</pattern>
</defs>
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" style="fill: #0000f4;"></rect>
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" fill="url(#pattern-stripe2)" style="stroke: steelblue; opacity: 1;"></rect>
</svg>
</svg>

<hr/>

<p>From code inspection, what is wanted</p>
<svg width="700" height="100">
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern-stripe3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(135)" width="7" height="23">
<rect width="2" height="23" fill="yellow" x="0" y="0"></rect>
</pattern>
</defs>
<g class="random-data-task" aria-selected="false" aria-describedby="task3">
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" style="fill: #f40000;"></rect>
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" fill="url(#pattern-stripe3)" style="stroke: #00f400; opacity: 1;"></rect>
</g>
</svg>

<hr/>

<p>With a single rect that has a pattern</p>
<svg width="700" height="100">
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern-stripe4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(135)" width="7" height="23">
<rect width="2" height="23" fill="yellow" x="0" y="0"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="23" fill="red" x="2" y="0"></rect>
</pattern>
</defs>
<g class="random-data-task" aria-selected="false" aria-describedby="task3">
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" fill="url(#pattern-stripe4)" style="stroke: #00f400; opacity: 1;"></rect>
</g>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

What exactly do you want to show/visualize with this overlay pattern?

**Edit**

I have added a shape based on the `width`s from your code and a shape with the same look but made with one rect with a pattern.

```
<svg width="700" height="300">
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern-stripe4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(135)" width="7" height="23">
<rect width="2" height="23" fill="yellow" x="0" y="0"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="23" fill="red" x="2" y="0"></rect>
</pattern>
</defs>
<g class="random-data-task" aria-selected="false" aria-describedby="task3">
    <rect x="53" y="50" width="341" height="23" class="random-data-bar" fill="url(#pattern-stripe4)" style="stroke: #00f400; opacity: 1;"></rect>
</g>
</svg>
```

To prevent the modification of the pattern `rect`s:

- do **not** select `rect`s without a class designation, the rects in the pattern are also selected and updated
- select `rect` based on class or as sub elements of a particular group

For axample

```
svg.selectAll(".bars")......
svg.select(".bargroup").selectAll("rect").....
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like, there is some redraw function in my app, which introduces the x and y co-ordinates for the pattern.

Comment: @DineshSingh: added two other svg examples, based on your code and one made with 1 rect and a different pattern.

Comment: @DineshSingh: do **not** select `rect`s without a class designation, the rects in the pattern are also selected and updated